# Lack of type inheritance using a backward chaining reasoner?

Tags: owl, reasoning

I'm learning about reasoning and knowledge engineering and I made up the following example:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl> .

[ rdf:type owl:Ontology
 ] .

:value rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
   rdfs:range xsd:string .

:humiditySensor rdf:type owl:Class ;
            rdfs:subClassOf :sensor .

:location rdf:type owl:Class .

:room rdf:type owl:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf :location .

:sensor rdf:type owl:Class.

:temperatureSensor rdf:type owl:Class ;
               rdfs:subClassOf :sensor .

:temp1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :temperatureSensor ;
    :room 201 ;
   :value 29 .
```

I'm trying to infer that temp1 is of type sensor. When I pose the following query to Eye reasoner (backward chaining) I get nothing, i.e. the fact that temp1 is of type sensor is not inferred, even though subClassOf is transitive:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org#>.
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.

{
    ?x a :sensor.
    ?x :value ?y.
}
=>
{
    ?x :value ?y.
}.
```

If I write a couple of rules manually to express this transitivity property of subClassOf, it will work. However, CWM reasoner (forward chaining) in the proof states correctly that temp1 is of type sensor, without the additional rules.

Is this because of the difference between forward and backward chaining?

I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: I cannot follow you because I don't which RDF API and which reasoner you use...in general, it depends on the reasoning profile that is used in forward resp. backward chaining.

Comment: Ok, I found the reference to the Eye reasoner: http://n3.restdesc.org/n3/

Comment: Indeed, the `rdfs:subClassOf` relation is transitive, but therefore you need RDFS entailment. Does the EYe reasoner implement this by default? If not, indeed you have to add those rules.

Comment: Thanks for your help.That's interesting. I'd think that those rules/entailments would be coded in rdf-s? Why not?

Comment: @BobRoy, minor comment `:value rdfs:range xsd:string`, but `temp1 :value 29` (i. e. `"29"^^xsd:integer` ?).

Comment: @BobRoy What do you mean "by coded in RDFS"? RDFS provides syntax and semantics. The transitivity of `rdfs:subClassOf` is indeed covered by the RDFS semantics. Sure, your Eye reasoner is a generic rule-based reasoner for RDF data in N3 format, but this doesn't mean that it covers any set of rules for RDFS entailment by default. It's a simple rule engine. Maybe I'm wrong, but at least I couldn't find any reference on the project page, thus, I assume to be right this time.

Comment: @AKSW This is my line of reasoning: 
RDF schema is a model for representing models. It defines the syntax and semantics. Some of those semantics are aforementioned entailments. So why are those entailments not represented in the file under http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema? Is it normal that those rules have to be added manually? 

My knowledge of this topic is still very limited, so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @StanislavKralin you're right, that's an error.